# What assumptions do we need on $f$ and $g$ for the equation $Df = f+g$ to be solveable in this way?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations, differential-operators

Suppose we're trying to solve a functional equation of the form 
$$Df = f+g,$$ where $D$ means differentiation, $g$ is given, and the goal is to find $f$.

One approach would be to rearrange to $$(D-1)f=g,$$

which becomes

$$f = \frac{1}{D-1} g$$

which becomes

$$f = \frac{-1}{1-D} g$$

which plausibly becomes

$$f = -(1+D+D^2+D^3+\cdots) g.$$

> **Question.** What assumptions do we need on $f$ and $g$ for this line of reasoning to actually work?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are of finite norm and the operator norm of $D$ is < 1.

Comment: @WillM., just to be clear, I intended $D$ to mean differentiation.

Comment: other solution is thinking that $\|D\|>1$, then the solution have the form $$-\frac1{1-D}=\frac1D\cdot\frac1{1-1/D}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty D^{-k-1}$$ However many times both solutions are true, that is, there is not an easy way to know the possible "meaning" to many differential operators.

Comment: Interesting observation: If we let $g(x) = \cos(x)$, then using the formula, we have $f(x) = -\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k(\cos(x)-\sin(x))\right)$, and using Cesaro summation gives the valid solution of $(\cos(x)-\sin(x))/2$.